# What is the fastest way of getting the list of lists containing a certain integer in a list of list of integers

Tags: python, list, loops, filtering

for example I have a list of list of integers like

```
x = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6], [2,3,1,9]]
```

Assume the length of x is in million. In that case iterating trough each element will be very slow.
Is there any faster way?

Comment: Please provide more information. Instead of a long title, add a more explanatory paragraph. But what would be most helpful is giving a full example of your input and what you expect as a result.

Comment: You should use "in" like: y =  [i for i in x if 1 in i] Creates a list with all lists that contain 1.

Answer (score 0):

Without any prior knowledge or extra information about the list (e.g., whether its sorted), you have no real choice but to iterate over the entire list. Note, however, that doing this with a generator could be must more performant than creating a filtered list, as the values are calculated just when you attempt to consume them, and not upfront:

```py
search = 2
listGenerator = (i for i in x if search in i)
```

Comment: but when the list is very large (like millions of lists in a list) it gets very slow

Comment: Can you index your lists beforehand?